# Callback method for AsyncHttpClient if internet connection with no data android Loopj

Tags: android, loopj, asynchttpclient

I am using Loopj to get a request and response. But it seems that callback method is not called properly if internet connection with no data.
When I click a listview its execute below code:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    System.out.println("onSuccess");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    System.out.println("onFailure");
                }

            });
```

Problem is that if internet connected but with no data then onFailure() is not calling even after timeout settings.

I have tried with below timeout settings in client:

> client.setTimeout(5000);

or

> client.setConnectTimeout(5000);

or

> client.setResponseTimeout(5000);

or

> client.setMaxRetriesAndTimeout(5,1000);

None of these forcing to call onFailure(). My question is there any way to call onFailure() if **internet connection with no data** or any other callback available in Loopj which fired after timeout?

Answer (score 0):

There are other callback for `AsyncHttpClient`, the most important are

```
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            System.out.println("onSuccess");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
            System.out.println("onFailure");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            super.onFinish();
            System.out.println("onFinish");
        }
    });
```

In your case you can use the `onFinish()` callback which will give the end of the wed request even if its success or failure..

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried but onFInish() is not called when internet connection with no data. Its keeps requesting until internet data availability.

Comment: Keeps requesting? Didn't get you..Can you please explain more. Or post screen shot or something? @0xAliHn

Comment: I mean onFinish() called after either onSuccess() or OnFailure(). In my case internet connection with no data both onSuccess() and onFailure() not getting fired. So, onFinish() also not getting called.

Comment: Ok.. I think if you are using `client.setMaxRetriesAndTimeout(5,1000);` then you can override `onRetry()` callback and do you task if retry count == 4 or your appropriate condition and cancel the request by calling `  client.cancelAllRequests(true);` @0xAliHn

Comment: if you need help with this suggestion, let me know, i will edit my answer @0xAliHn

Comment: Strange..onRetry() method also not calling after setMaxRetriesAndTimeout(5,1000).